# Is there a list of Error Numbers for VB6?

Tags: vb6

I am handling errors with the

```
on error goto
```

statement, and when the error processing is activated, I wish to handle the errors something like this...

```
If Err.Number = this Then
   do_this
ElseIf Err.Number = that Then
    do_that
Else
    do_the_other
End If
```

To do this, though, relies on knowing what errors generate which numbers. Is there a list of these anywhere (I have been unable to find one)?

Comment: Try this link [http://www.pscode.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=48434&lngWId=1](http://www.pscode.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=48434&lngWId=1)

Comment: PSC linked moved to https://github.com/Planet-Source-Code/matt-stafford-vb6-error-codes-list__1-48434

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are the core Visual Basic 6.0 language errors:

[*Trappable Errors - Visual Basic for Applications Reference - 
Visual Studio 6.0*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264975%28v=VS.60%29.aspx)

Searching for "Trappable errors" also produces such list [for VS 2008](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms234761(v=vs.90).aspx) (i.e. Office 2007) and [a list for an unspecified version dated 2006](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/142138/an-explanation-of-trappable-errors-in-visual-basic-for-apps) (so must be Office 2003).

Answer (score 5):

Summon help (f1 key), select the index tab and type in 'trappable errors'.

(assumes you have vb6 help installed)